# IronPython - Install comtypes

Tags: python, ironpython

How can I add comtypes to IronPython? I need to grab an object from Windows ROT to execute a few commands using its API. With pure python I can use `comtypes.cliend.GetActiveObject()`. I have a few python distributions on my computer: one installed with anaconda, other stand alone and also IronPython2.7.

Answer (score 0):

IronPython is part of the dotNET framework, so you should probably be looking in dotNET documentation. I am not familiar with the Windows Running Object Table (ROT), but I imagine that you could use the clr module to import the relevant libraries.

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("xxx.dll")
```